# How do I resolve a soft close drawer mechanism not working correctly?

Tags: kitchen-counters, drawers

I just moved in to a new house and 2 of the soft-close drawers don't work correctly. The model is Blum (it's an older version I think). [image]

It looks like the one in the picture, and the issue is that the orange bit snaps very quickly rather than moving slowly like it happens in the ones that work properly.

Any advice?

Comment: The unit is defective. You need to get a new one.  Try online.  Take the part out and look for a part number.  Google Blum and the number.

Comment: Is this a "new build" house, or a "new to you" house? If it's a new build, then it's on the builder/contractor to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Old things can wear out.

It's probably time to contact Blum to see if they'll sell you replacement parts that you can swap out, or to purchase new drawer slides and completely replace these.